# How to get my Note 9 to read aloud incoming email ONLY from one specific Gmail account?

Tags: gmail

Any way to do this? Tried various apps but they read out all email accounts. Want to setup my phone to read incoming emails out loud from one specific user too if possible.

Comment: @beeshyams with my eyes. need way to listen to incoming email from one of my gmail accounts. waiting for important email but can't have phone stuck to me 24 hrs a day. need the subject line & body read aloud.

Answer (score 4):

[FairEmail](https://email.faircode.eu/)
since [version 1.1254](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=83079481&postcount=15164) released on 17 Jul 20, allows you to read out aloud  mails from selected sender(s).

A big shout out to Marcel, the developer who accepted this feature request and implemented it. I have tested it thoroughly over the last few days (I had a test version much prior to the formal release) and it works faultlessly for me.

Here is how you do that :

Create a rule:

Go to the **inbox** of your primary account, long press → Edit rules and tap on the **+** icon to create a new rule.

- Set *order* to 1 (lower the order, higher the processing priority). Make sure the rule is enabled.
- In the *Sender Contains*  enter email address of the sender.
- In the *Recipient Contains* enter email address of the recipient.
- Type and *not* copy-paste email addresses (at times copy-paste has invisible blanks which can break the expected behavior)
- Leave *Subject Contains* blank.
- Select *Action* as *Text to Speech*
- Press Check setup. If it says OK, you are set up, else *install voice data*(TTS engine).

[automation](/questions/tagged/automation) approach had mixed results. You can read about them in [previous version](https://android.stackexchange.com/revisions/226366/13) of the answer

**Notes**

- You need the paid version of FairEmail.
- The rule should be created in inbox folder of the **recipient** account.
- At the cost of repetition, leave the subject on the rule blank
- This is for one sender. If you want this action for more senders, you need to create more rules as explained. You need to create one rule per sender (tip: you can long press a rule to copy and edit, instead of starting all over again) .
- The mail text that is read out is limited to the text that is contained in the notification text, that is 500 characters (Android limitation of notification text size). IMO, this is more than enough to get the message in full most of the times (unless it's a very long mail).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110066/discussion-on-answer-by-beeshyams-how-to-get-my-note-9-to-read-aloud-incoming-em).