# How to use a custom notification sound in gmail when email received from a specific contact

Tags: notifications, gmail

I am a volunteer firefighter and when we get an alarm, I receive an email from a specific address.  I would like to be able to change the notification sound the gmail android app uses when any email from this address is received.  I believe there used to be a way to configure a label in gmail and set a custom notification sound for that label, but that feature seems to have been removed in more recent versions of android.  Is there any way to do this with the current gmail app?

Comment: If you are willing to change your Gmail app and use an open source app, you can have notifications set up and also have the message read out aloud. [See answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/226322)

Comment: You could use something like *Tasker* or *Automate* to detect these emails and act appropriately.